# Bash flatten an array to key value pair

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I have an array mentioned below.

**Array**

```
wf.example.input1=/path/to/file1 
wf.example.input2=/path/to/file2 
wf.example.input3=["/path/to/file3","/path/to/file4"]
```

`declare -p Array` gives me below output.

```
([0]="wf.example.input1=/path/to/file1" [1]="wf.example.input2=/path/to/file2" [2]="wf.example.input3=[\"/path/to/file3\",\"/path/to/file4\"]")
```

I need to flatten this array ib bash script and give me output like below.

**Output**

```
name:"wf.example.input1", value:"/path/to/file1"
name:"wf.example.input2", value:"/path/to/file2"
name:"wf.example.input3", value:"/path/to/file3"
name:"wf.example.input3", value:"/path/to/file4"
```

Comment: @anubhava This array will be coming as an input to me. I am not the one creating this array. And i need to generate desired output as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Whatever input you are getting, you can examine it using `declare -p array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `printf` piped to `awk` to get formatting:

```
declare -a arr='([0]="wf.example.input1=/path/to/file1"
[1]="wf.example.input2=/path/to/file2"
[2]="wf.example.input3=[\"/path/to/file3\",\"/path/to/file4\"]")'

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" |
awk -F= '{
   n=split($2, a, /,/)
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
      gsub(/^[^"]*"|"[^"]*$/, "", a[i])
      printf "name:\"%s\", value:\"%s\"\n", $1, a[i]
   }
}'
```

**Output:**

```
name:"wf.example.input1", value:"/path/to/file1"
name:"wf.example.input2", value:"/path/to/file2"
name:"wf.example.input3", value:"/path/to/file3"
name:"wf.example.input3", value:"/path/to/file4"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I required. +1