# can't figure out multidimensional arrays while trying to automate Rules insertion for my Unified Firewall

Tags: bash, shell, multidimensional-array, increment, iptables

I am trying to automate **Rules** insertion for my **Firewall**... using **Shell** but i am kind of beginner with **Shell** Coding...

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ! $EUID -eq 0 && ! $USER -eq "root" ]]; then
   echo "You're not running as administator(root)!";
   exit 1;
fi

declare -i allowRulesIDX=0;
declare -a allowRules;
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1)); // Line number 10
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(80 "TLS/HTTP" "Local"); // Line number 11
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(443 "SSL/HTTPS" "Local");
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=3306 "MySQL" "Local");
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(53 "DNS" "Local");
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(68 "DHCP" "Local");
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(5353 "mDNS" "Local");
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(853 "DNS" "Local");
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(546 "DHCPv6" "Local");
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(547 "DHCPv6" "Local");
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(123 "NTP" "Local");
$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));
$allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(5000 "UPnP" "Local");
declare -i rejectRulesIDX=0;
declare -a rejectRules;
$rejectRulesIDX=$((rejectRulesIDX+1));
$rejectRules[$rejectRulesIDX]=(5900 "VNC" "Anywhere");
declare -i RulesActionIDX=0;
declare -a RulesAction;
$RulesActionIDX=$((RulesActionIDX+1));
$RulesAction[$RulesActionIDX+1]=(${allowRules[@]} allow);
$RulesActionIDX=$((RulesActionIDX+1));
$RulesAction[$RulesActionIDX+1]=(${rejectRules[@]} reject);
for action in ${RulesAction[@]};
do
    for rule in ${{action[0]}[@]};
    do
        for entry in ${rule[@]};
        do
               for $port in $(([[ ${entry[0]} =~ - ]] && {$((${entry[0]} | cut --fields=1 --delimiter=-))..$((${entry[0]} | cut --fields=2 --delimiter=-))} || ${entry[0]}));
               do
                  for proto in udp tcp;
                  do
                            for direction in in out;
                            do
                                if [[ ${entry[2]} -eq "Anywhere" ]]; then
                                    echo ufw ${action[1]} $direction log-all proto $proto from any to any port $port comment ${entry[1]};
                                elif [[ ${entry[2]} -eq "Local" ]]; then
                                    for localTarget in 127.0.0.0/24 192.168.1.0/24;
                                    do
                                        echo ufw ${action[1]} $direction log-all proto $proto from $localTarget to any port $port comment ${entry[1]};
                                    done;
                                else
                                    echo ufw ${action[1]} $direction log-all proto $proto from ${entry[2]} to any port $port comment ${entry[1]};
                                fi
                             done;
                  done;
            done;
        done;
    done;
done;

# Must always be the last line
exit 0;
```

- please note that i am **printing** the commands (not **executing** them) for debugging reasons.

and it results in:

```
line 10: 0=1: command not found
line 11: syntax error near unexpected token 80
```

I am trying some tricky techniques to implement multidimensional arrays within the variable but it seems like I can't implement it correctly
and variable's value is somehow being executed instead of being increased ??

Comment: The shell barely handles flat arrays.

Comment: @Ouroborus i tried doing it like https://stackoverflow.com/a/45102172/8704593 but that didn't work too

Comment: Bash doesn't have multidimensional arrays. *AT ALL*. You also have a huge number of syntax errors, like using `$var=value` (you use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, not to *set* it), using `-eq` to compare strings (it does numeric comparison), using the wrong comment marker, etc. I'd recommend 1) starting with something simpler and 2) using [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to check for common scripting mistakes.

Comment: If the things you're trying to store don't have anything but alphanumeric characters (especially, no spaces/tabs/newlines, `*`, `?`, `[` or `]`), you might be able to get away with storing each "row" as a single string, and using word-splitting to separate it into "columns".

Comment: Please clean up the syntax. Use _real_ Bash arithmetics instead of “looks like legacy shell, won’t work in legacy shell” style. Also, Bash is not PHP… Instead of `$allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));`, what you need is `((++allowRulesIdx))`. Or even better, `allowRules[allowRulesIDX++]='80 "TLS/HTTP" "Local"'`. Which is still flawed; if you just do `allowRules+=(80 "TLS/HTTP" "Local")`, you add 3 elements to the array; `allowRules+=('80 "TLS/HTTP" "Local"')` adds one. **There are no multi-dimensional arrays in Bash.** You can “simulate” them using dynamic name generation and `declare -n`.

Comment: specifically addressing the error ... `line 10 ==> $allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1));` ... both sides of the `=` are replaced with their corresponding values, namely: `0=$((0+1))` => `0=1`, which in turn `bash` tries to process as a *command* but since `0=1` is not a valid command the error is generated,: `0=1: command not found` (ie, `0=1` is not a valid command); for assignments the left side of the `=` does *not* start with a `$` so line 10 should be: `allowRulesIDX=$(($allowRulesIDX+1))`

Comment: as for the 2nd error re: line 11 ... removing the 1st `$` from the left side will leave us with `allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]=(80 "TLS/HTTP" "Local")` (the `$` is required on the left for `$allowRulesIDX` since we're referencing the value stored in the variable) which should generate an error like: `allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]: cannot assign list to array member` which is another way of saying you cannot assign an array of values to another array ... this is an error because `bash` does not support multi-dimensional arrays (aka arrays of arrays)

Comment: Try to write a very small bash script first, e.g. one off some online bash tutorial. Once you can get that working, then try something a bit more complicated, and so on to learn a bit about bash incrementally and work yourself up to trying to do something like you're trying to do here.

Comment: all the above are true, but ++ for using `echo ufw ...` to debug your process. That is a good place to start.  I would at using `awk` to generate your list of rules and then feed that output to `ufw` via a pipe. Good luck!

Comment: I used your suggestions and it is almost working but it doesn't reach the echo command (print anything to the console) for some reason :( [The Code(Sorry but i can't paste the code into this comment because of the characters limit)](https://pastebin.com/2uTBgSge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put some time into this because I intend create a derivative to convert my customized [iptables](/questions/tagged/iptables) coding/rules to [nftables](/questions/tagged/nftables) (*the designated iptables replacement*).

I love doing stuff with **[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)**, and I tried **very hard** to make it work for bash only, but that became far too frustrating.

I abandoned bash to do a re-write using **[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)** as the main workhorse.  If there are thousands of rules, awk will be a much better choice for this type of parsing/translation.

The below script will perform what I believe to be the logic you put forward above, but there was some ambiguity arising from what I feel was a malformed statement for the "**[[ ${entry[0]} =~ - ]]**" condition.  I made the interpretation that such cases are ranges and don't need to be "split up".

Also, there are cases where you would encounter **comma-separated** lists, which again you wouldn't want to split up, so I modified the format of the input to use the vertical bar (or pipe, "|") for field delimiter.

You will also notice that I again modified it to add the **accept/reject** specification as the first field (**"class"**) for each specification line.

I also did not quite understand what you were trying to do for Target values other than "Anywhere" or "Local".  If possible, I would suggest you consider defining the specifications without the double quotes around those to reduce the parsing and logical efforts involved.

One other comment.  Maybe not for the above limited ruleset, but you may wish to **be mindfull of the order in which you define you specifications**.  That order **WILL** have impact on what is allowed thru the firewall and might prevent what you would otherwise want to allow.

The below is the resulting code logic.  I hope it works for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! $EUID -eq 0 && ! $USER -eq "root" ]]; then
    echo "You're not running as administator(root)!";
    exit 1;
fi

DBG=0


#declare -i allowRulesIDX=0;
#declare -A allowRules;
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=80,[comment]="TLS/HTTP",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=443,[comment]="SSL/HTTPS",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=3306,[comment]="MySQL",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=53,[comment]="DNS",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=68,[comment]="DHCP",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=5353,[comment]="mDNS",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=853,[comment]="DNS",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=546,[comment]="DHCPv6",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=547,[comment]="DHCPv6",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=123,[comment]="NTP",[target]="Local"';
#allowRulesIDX=$((++allowRulesIdx));
#allowRules[$allowRulesIDX]='[port]=5000,[comment]="UPnP",[target]="Local"';
#
#
#declare -i rejectRulesIDX=0;
#declare -A rejectRules;
#rejectRulesIDX=$(($rejectRulesIDX+1));
#rejectRules[$rejectRulesIDX]='[port]=5900,[comment]="VNC",[target]="Anywhere"';


### NOTE:  Commas as delimiter are not ideal because some of the fields could have commas, causing confusion/difficulties for proper parsing.
###     Vertical bar (or pipe, "|") is a better choice for delimiter.
RULES_FILE="FW_rules.txt"
cat >"${RULES_FILE}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
[class]=allow|[port]=80|[target]="Local"|[comment]="TLS/HTTP"
[class]=allow|[port]=443|[target]="Local"|[comment]="SSL/HTTPS"
[class]=allow|[port]=3306|[target]="Local"|[comment]="MySQL"
[class]=allow|[port]=53|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DNS"
[class]=allow|[port]=68|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DHCP"
[class]=allow|[port]=5353|[target]="Local"|[comment]="mDNS"
[class]=allow|[port]=853|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DNS"
[class]=allow|[port]=546|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DHCPv6"
[class]=allow|[port]=547|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DHCPv6"
[class]=allow|[port]=123|[target]="Local"|[comment]="NTP"
[class]=allow|[port]=5000,95,303|[target]="Local"|[comment]="UPnP"
[class]=reject|[port]=5900|[target]="Anywhere"|[comment]="VNC"
EnDoFiNpUt

awk -F "|" -v dbg="${DBG}" 'BEGIN{
    ufwRulesIDX=0 ;
    split("", ufwRules) ;

    allowRulesIDX=0 ;
    split("", allowRules) ;

    rejectRulesIDX=0 ;
    split("", rejectRules) ;

    split("", Actions) ;
    Actions[1]="accept" ;
    Actions[2]="reject" ;

    split("", Protos) ;
    Protos[1]="udp" ;
    Protos[2]="tcp" ;

    split("", Directions) ;
    Directions[1]="in" ;
    Directions[2]="out" ;

    split("", LocalTargets) ;
    LocalTargets[1]="127.0.0.0/24" ;
    LocalTargets[2]="192.168.1.0/24" ;

    port=1 ;
    target=2 ;
    comment=3 ;
    unknown=4 ;
    br1="[" ;
    br2="]" ;
}{
    if( $0 == "" ){
        exit ;
    } ;

    ufwRulesIDX++ ;
    ufwRules[ufwRulesIDX]=$0 ;
    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#\n#*** ufwRules[%s] = '%s' ...\n", ufwRulesIDX, ufwRules[ufwRulesIDX] ) ; } ;

    split("", hold) ;

    for( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ ){
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("# $%s = %s ...\n", i, $i ) ; } ;
        #[class]=allow|[port]=5000|[target]="Local"|[comment]="UPnP"
        split("", tmp) ;    # initialize to empty
        split($i, tmp, "=") ;

        gsub(/\[/, "", tmp[1] ) ;
        gsub(/\]/, "", tmp[1] ) ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#\t tmp[1] = %s\n", tmp[1] ) ; } ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#\t tmp[2] = %s\n", tmp[2] ) ; } ;

        switch (tmp[1]) {
            case "class" :  {
                assign=tmp[2];
                if( dbg == 1 ){ print "#\t\t assign = ", assign ; }
                break ;
            } ;
            case "port" :   {
                hold[port]=tmp[2] ;
                break ;
            } ;
            case "target" : {
                hold[target]=tmp[2] ;
                break ;
            } ;
            case "comment" : {
                hold[comment]=tmp[2] ;
                break ;
            } ;
            default :   {
                printf("\t Unrecognized field label '%s' in rule [NR]:  %s\n" ) ; break ;
                hold[unknown]=tmp[2] ;
            } ;
        } ;
    } ;
    switch (assign) {
        case "allow" : {
            allowRulesIDX++ ;
            allowRules[allowRulesIDX,port]=hold[port] ;
            allowRules[allowRulesIDX,target]=hold[target] ;
            allowRules[allowRulesIDX,comment]=hold[comment] ;
            allowRules[allowRulesIDX,unknown]=hold[unknown] ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){ print "#\t allowRulesIDX = ", allowRulesIDX ; } ;
            break ;
        } ;
        case "reject" : {
            rejectRulesIDX++ ;
            rejectRules[rejectRulesIDX,port]=hold[port] ;
            rejectRules[rejectRulesIDX,target]=hold[target] ;
            rejectRules[rejectRulesIDX,comment]=hold[comment] ;
            rejectRules[rejectRulesIDX,unknown]=hold[unknown] ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){ print "#\t rejectRulesIDX = ", rejectRulesIDX ; } ;
            break ;
        } ;
    } ;

}END{
    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#S\n#S================== INPUT DEFINITIONS =====================\n") ; } ;

    for( i=1 ; i<=ufwRulesIDX ; i++ ){
        printf("#S\t [%02d] = %s\n", i, ufwRules[i] ) ;
    } ;

    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#A\n#A================== ALLOW RULES =====================\n") ; } ;
    for( i=1 ; i <= allowRulesIDX ; i++ ){
        printf("#A\t [A %02d] = ", i ) ;
        for( j=1 ; j<=3 ; j++ ){
            printf(" %s |", allowRules[i,j] ) ;
        } ;
        printf("\n") ;
    } ;

    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#R\n#R================== REJECT RULES =====================\n") ; } ;
    for( i=1 ; i <= rejectRulesIDX ; i++ ){
        printf("#R\t [R %02d] = ", i ) ;
        for( j=1 ; j<=3 ; j++ ){
            printf(" %s |", rejectRules[i,j] ) ;
        } ;
        printf("\n") ;
    } ;

    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UA\n#UA================== UFW ALLOW RULES =====================\n") ; } ;
    for( i=1 ; i <= allowRulesIDX ; i++ ){
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UA\t allowRules[%02d,port] = %s ...\n", i, allowRules[i,port] ) ; } ;
        n=split(allowRules[i,port], Ports, "," ) ;
        for( j=1 ; j<=n ; j++ ){
            if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UA\t Ports[%02d] = %s ...\n", j, Ports[j] ) ; } ;
            for( k=1 ; k<=2 ; k++ ){
                if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UA\t Protos[%02d] = %s ...\n", k, Protos[k] ) ; } ;
                for( m=1 ; m<=2 ; m++ ){
                    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UA\t Directions[%02d] = %s ...\n", m, Directions[m] ) ; } ;
                    Target=allowRules[allowRulesIDX,target] ;
                    gsub(/"/, "", Target ) ;
                    switch (Target) {
                        case "Anywhere" : {
                            if(dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UAA\t\t Target = %s\n", Target ) ; } ;
                            printf("ufw %s %s log-all Proto %s from any to any port %s comment %s\n", Actions[1], Directions[m], Protos[k], Ports[j], allowRules[allowRulesIDX,comment] ) ;
                            break ;
                        } ;
                        case "Local" : {
                            if(dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UAL\t\t Target = %s\n", Target ) ; } ;
                            for( p=1 ; p<=2 ; p++ ){
                                if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UL\t LocalTargets[%02d] = %s ...\n", p, LocalTargets[p] ) ; } ;
                                printf("ufw %s %s log-all Proto %s from %s to any port %s comment %s\n", Actions[1], Directions[m], Protos[k], LocalTargets[p], Ports[j], allowRules[allowRulesIDX,comment] ) ;
                            } ;
                            break ;
                        } ;
                        default : {
                            if(dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UAO\t\t Target = %s\n", Target ) ; } ;
                            printf("ufw %s %s log-all Proto %s from %s to any port %s comment %s\n", Actions[1], Directions[m], Protos[k], allowRules[allowRulesIDX,target], Ports[j], allowRules[allowRulesIDX,comment] ) ;
                            break ;
                        } ;
                    } ;
                } ;
            } ;
            
        } ;
    } ;

    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UR\n#UR================== UFW REJECT RULES =====================\n") ; } ;
    for( i=1 ; i <= rejectRulesIDX ; i++ ){
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UR\t rejectRules[%02d,port] = %s ...\n", i, rejectRules[i,port] ) ; } ;
        n=split(rejectRules[i,port], Ports, "," ) ;
        for( j=1 ; j<=n ; j++ ){
            if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UR\t Ports[%02d] = %s ...\n", j, Ports[j] ) ; } ;
            for( k=1 ; k<=2 ; k++ ){
                if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UR\t Protos[%02d] = %s ...\n", k, Protos[k] ) ; } ;
                for( m=1 ; m<=2 ; m++ ){
                    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#UR\t Directions[%02d] = %s ...\n", m, Directions[m] ) ; } ;
                    Target=rejectRules[rejectRulesIDX,target] ;
                    gsub(/"/, "", Target ) ;
                    switch (Target) {
                        case "Anywhere" : {
                            if(dbg == 1 ){ printf("#URA\t\t Target = %s\n", Target ) ; } ;
                            printf("ufw %s %s log-all Proto %s from any to any port %s comment %s\n", Actions[2], Directions[m], Protos[k], Ports[j], rejectRules[rejectRulesIDX,comment] ) ;
                            break ;
                        } ;
                        case "Local" : {
                            if(dbg == 1 ){ printf("#URL\t\t Target = %s\n", Target ) ; } ;
                            for( p=1 ; p<=2 ; p++ ){
                                if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("#\t LocalTargets[%02d] = %s ...\n", p, LocalTargets[p] ) ; } ;
                                printf("ufw %s %s log-all Proto %s from %s to any port %s comment %s\n", Actions[2], Directions[m], Protos[k], LocalTargets[p], Ports[j], rejectRules[rejectRulesIDX,comment] ) ;
                            } ;
                            break ;
                        } ;
                        default : {
                            if(dbg == 1 ){ printf("#URO\t\t Target = %s\n", Target ) ; } ;
                            printf("ufw %s %s log-all Proto %s from %s to any port %s comment %s\n", Actions[2], Directions[m], Protos[k], rejectRules[rejectRulesIDX,target], Ports[j], rejectRules[rejectRulesIDX,comment] ) ;
                            break ;
                        } ;
                    } ;
                } ;
            } ;
            
        } ;
    } ;
}' "${RULES_FILE}"

exit 0
```

Session log is as follows:

```
#S   [01] = [class]=allow|[port]=80|[target]="Local"|[comment]="TLS/HTTP"
#S   [02] = [class]=allow|[port]=443|[target]="Local"|[comment]="SSL/HTTPS"
#S   [03] = [class]=allow|[port]=3306|[target]="Local"|[comment]="MySQL"
#S   [04] = [class]=allow|[port]=53|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DNS"
#S   [05] = [class]=allow|[port]=68|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DHCP"
#S   [06] = [class]=allow|[port]=5353|[target]="Local"|[comment]="mDNS"
#S   [07] = [class]=allow|[port]=853|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DNS"
#S   [08] = [class]=allow|[port]=546|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DHCPv6"
#S   [09] = [class]=allow|[port]=547|[target]="Local"|[comment]="DHCPv6"
#S   [10] = [class]=allow|[port]=123|[target]="Local"|[comment]="NTP"
#S   [11] = [class]=allow|[port]=5000,95,303|[target]="Local"|[comment]="UPnP"
#S   [12] = [class]=reject|[port]=5900|[target]="Anywhere"|[comment]="VNC"
#A   [A 01] =  80 | "Local" | "TLS/HTTP" |
#A   [A 02] =  443 | "Local" | "SSL/HTTPS" |
#A   [A 03] =  3306 | "Local" | "MySQL" |
#A   [A 04] =  53 | "Local" | "DNS" |
#A   [A 05] =  68 | "Local" | "DHCP" |
#A   [A 06] =  5353 | "Local" | "mDNS" |
#A   [A 07] =  853 | "Local" | "DNS" |
#A   [A 08] =  546 | "Local" | "DHCPv6" |
#A   [A 09] =  547 | "Local" | "DHCPv6" |
#A   [A 10] =  123 | "Local" | "NTP" |
#A   [A 11] =  5000,95,303 | "Local" | "UPnP" |
#R   [R 01] =  5900 | "Anywhere" | "VNC" |
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 80 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 80 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 80 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 80 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 443 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 443 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 443 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 443 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 443 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 443 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 443 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 443 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 3306 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3306 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 3306 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3306 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 3306 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3306 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 3306 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3306 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 53 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 53 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 53 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 53 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 53 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 53 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 53 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 53 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 68 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 68 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 68 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 68 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 68 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 68 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 68 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 68 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 5353 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 5353 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 5353 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 5353 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 5353 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 5353 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 5353 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 5353 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 853 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 853 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 853 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 853 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 853 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 853 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 853 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 853 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 546 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 546 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 546 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 546 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 546 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 546 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 546 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 546 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 547 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 547 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 547 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 547 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 547 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 547 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 547 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 547 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 123 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 123 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 123 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 123 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 123 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 123 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 123 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 123 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 5000 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 5000 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 5000 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 5000 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 5000 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 5000 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 5000 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 5000 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 95 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 95 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 95 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 95 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 95 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 95 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 95 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 95 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 303 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 303 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 303 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 303 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 303 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept in log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 303 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 127.0.0.0/24 to any port 303 comment "UPnP"
ufw accept out log-all Proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 303 comment "UPnP"
ufw reject in log-all Proto udp from any to any port 5900 comment "VNC"
ufw reject out log-all Proto udp from any to any port 5900 comment "VNC"
ufw reject in log-all Proto tcp from any to any port 5900 comment "VNC"
ufw reject out log-all Proto tcp from any to any port 5900 comment "VNC"
```